# Pointer doesn’t receives the value of 'arr'

Tags: c, function, pointers

The function receives pointer and the length of the 'arr'.
I tried to swap places in the 'arr' using a pointer.

It tells me:

> Exception thrown: write access violation.

p1 was 0x4D1335.

The function:

```
void func(int *ptr,int len)
{
    int *p1 = ptr;
    int i;
    int save = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        *p1++;
        printf("%d", *p1);
    }

    while (ptr != p1 || count != len/2)
    {
        count++;
        save = *ptr;   // The error is here (Exception thrown: write access violation.p1 was 0x4D1335.)
        *ptr = *p1;
        *p1 = save;
        *ptr++;
        *p1--;
    }
}
```

main():

```
void main()
{
    int arr[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    int *ptr = &arr[0];
    int i;
    func(ptr, 3);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

If someone has any idea way, it would be very helpful :)

Comment: Proposing pencil and paper.

Comment: The code reads and writes off the end of the array. The line `*p1++;` is suspicious (this increments `p1` and does a dereference whose result you never use), maybe you intended something else on this line.  Once that loop finishes, `p1` points past the last element of the array (and the last loop iteration read off end). Then the next loop will try to swap the first value with the value past the end of the array.

Comment: There are further redundant derefences in the second loop , `*x--;` has the same effect as `x--;` if you do not use the result

Comment: I think `||` should be `&&` This error is causing you to go way outside the array.

Comment: @Barmar just the second condition by itself should suffice ? maybe with an off-by-one adjustment

Comment: @M.M Possibly, I didn't really think about the entire logic, just the fact that `||` means the condition will always be true and it's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to explain the correct code below in func(). Please be aware that
*ptr++ is equivalent to *(ptr++), i.e., you are incrementing the pointer to the next element and dereferencing that location, and this can cause an issue at the array end.

```
void func(int *ptr, int len)
{
    int *p1 = ptr;
    int i;
    int save = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *p1);
        p1++;  // <-----------------------Increase the p1
    }

    --p1;      // <-----------Decrease the p1 by 1, as it points to one
               // location after array end.

    while (count != len/2)
    {
        count++;
        save = *ptr;
        *ptr = *p1;
        *p1 = save;
        ptr++;  // <----------increase the pointer
        p1--;   // <----------decrease the p1
    }
}
```